# When send photo url this error appear wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified

Tags: python, telegram

To bring an easy case to analyze different from the other existing questions, I brought a real URL that contains an image publicly accessible to everyone and that I tested using it in several other things:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36"
    }

def send_photo(id_chat,bot_token,text_msg,file_photo):
    address = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendPhoto'
    data = {"chat_id": id_chat, "photo": file_photo, "caption": text_msg}
    response = requests.post(address, data=data, headers=headers)
    print(json.loads(response.text))

send_photo('AAA', 'BBB', 'test', 'https://redecanais.to/imgs-videos/Series/Anos-Luz%201.jpg')
```

The error delivered is:

```
{'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified'}
```

How should I proceed to make this URL work as a value?

Note: I understand that downloading the photo and using it as a file to send would be an option, but I want to understand why the error occurs and how I should proceed using URL's directly.

If you want to review the documentation:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to pass the photo url, the url should be accessible by Telegram servers.
Apparently without the correct headers we receive a Access Denied error page.

Hence, you should download the image locally and upload the file as multipart/form-data